# vscode で、画面をほどよくスクロールし、カーソル行を真ん中にもってきたい

Tags: vscode

vscode において、 emacs における `C-l` 相当のことがやりたいと思いました。何かというと、現在のカーソル行が真ん中(や、もしくは画面上・下)にくるように、画面をスクロールする機能です。

このような機能は vscode にはありますでしょうか。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

標準の機能ではありませんが、Center Editor Windowという拡張機能が `C-l` 相当の機能を提供しているようです。

[Center Editor Window - Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kaiwood.center-editor-window)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

vim keybinding を利用している場合には、 `zz` でひとまずは実現出来る様子です。